# Login design in app with sqlite database and content provider

Tags: android, database, authentication, server

I am making an android app which downloads data from a server and I have implemented a sqlite database where the data from the server is stored and a Content provider, all of that to make the app work without internet connection. The thing is that the app needs the user to login in order to work, and that requires internet connection so the thing is which is the best way to allow users to login without connection? Because I think it makes no sense to have an app that works without connection if the users can not access it without internet. I thought about storing users and passwords that logged in in that device in a sqlite database the same way server data is stored and check from there, but is that safe? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like cache the logon credentials?

You're using some strong password based key derivation (like pbkdf2) to store the password on the server - if the user successfully "logs in", why not generate another strongly salted+strongly hashed copy of the password in your local SQLite database, so you can re-authenticate the user (for up to a certain expiry date) even if no internet connection is available?  (You should expire that cached set of credentials after a period of time - requiring an internet connection again to continue.  48 hours or something seems sane to me.)

Is that what you're after?

---

The major implication of this is if someone steals or otherwise gains access to the phone's SQLite database, they have the hashed password.  So make sure it's stored as securely as possible.  (There's plenty on this online - take a look at NIST's publications on the subject; *never* implicitly trust code you find online...)  If that crypto is strong enough, nothing is lost.

(If the user's "online" password is forced to be rotated every 90 days and it takes more than 90 days to crack the cached copy - nothing is lost.)

Your implementation of the login code will first try contacting the server to authenticate - if that fails, it'll check if there are locally cached credentials which have not yet expired, and authenticate locally against those (using code similar to on your server-side).

Comment: Thank you @wally for explaining everything so well, that was a great answer! I know what to do now :)